# Magento 1.9 mobile menu not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, mobile-menu

I had a problem with scrolling on the mobile menu for my [iacado.ro](http://iacado.ro) website.
I managed to make it to scroll (the people that made the website didn't do it).

[image: screenshot with css]

The problem is that although now it's scrolling, you can't "touch" anything on the screen even if the menu is closed.
Let me know if you need any other info:  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);` remove it and it will works, check also if you will have any issue.

```
.nav-container.mobile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

**Update:**

Update this:

```
.nav-container.mobile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Add this

```
.nav-container.mobile.collapsed {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Add this js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
     jQuery(".menu-button").click(function() {
         jQuery(".nav-container.mobile").toggleClass("collapsed");
     });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I've done that, but the menu looks like this: https://imgur.com/vKMzqFV . And you still can't click on anything under it. Thanks

Comment: "min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);" is still in the css when I checked it (1min ago) when I removed it it works fine for me

Comment: Done. I removed it. But like i said. The drop-down menu is too small and you can't press properly on any of the links. Maybe i wasn't clear with my question. I want to have the height of the drop-down menu to cover as much of the mobile screen (so you can press easily on the categories + subcategories) but still be able to press on whatever is on the page.

Comment: add this : `height: 100vh;`

Comment: it was working in chrome, but yeah i got the same issue in firefox and my phone.  Prince's solution seem to work

Comment: Yes it solves the height problem of the drop-down menu, but the initial problem of not being able to press anything on the page under the menu is not solved. With @Prince 's height modification, the drop-down menu now is covering the whole screen. But you can only press on the top-menu and on the drop-down menu (once you select it), but on the actual page you can't.

Comment: Look my update...

Comment: Please look the update

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately i'm new to this and i have no idea where/how to add that .js. If you can explain, please. Thanks.

Comment: If you could let me know where to add that .js would be great!

Comment: You can add it in your menu file `header.phtml`

Comment: @Prince thank you ! I had to add `overflow-y: auto;` to `.nav-container.mobile.collapsed` and it worked! Thanks again

Comment: wooh finally. Great you're welcome

Comment: Thanks to accept the answer if it's good for you

Comment: I want to, but it won't let me since i'm new here.

Comment: Even you are new here, it's your own question you can accept it, but you can't upvote ofcourse, in my question under the point 1 you have some checkbox, just click on it